In the list of figure, I want to delete spaces between figure list for the next chapter
There is a gap between different chapter's figures in the list of figures also in list of tables. I want to eliminate this gap.  

Welcome. // Things will be easier once you provide a MWE ... // Remember, you are typesetting in Latex, not typewriting ...

Solution depends on the class/setup you use, so as requested pleasse provide a full but minimal example so we can get an idea as to what you are doing.

If you are using a KOMA-Script class, try, e.g., option listof=nochaptergap. Otherwise → https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964

If you look into your aux or lof file you will see something like \@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}.  You could use \let\addvspace=\@gobble, but you need to make it local to \listoffigures and use \makeatletter ... \makeatother.
